# Cannot save Firestore query in a list

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

basically I need to save in a list the fields of a collection in a firestore database.

This is the widget that takes care of connecting to the database:

```
  Future<QuerySnapshot> MissionRetriever1() async{
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("quest")
        .doc("1")
        .get();
    }
```

And this is the widget contained in another file that takes care of saving the various data in a List :

```
  Future<void> getMission1() async{
   var snap = await widget.mservice.MissionRetriever1();
   for(var doc in snap.docs){
     MissionData1.add(doc.data()['Q_Category']);
     MissionData1.add(doc.data()['Q_Name']);
     MissionData1.add(doc.data()['Q_Description']);
     MissionData1.add(doc.data()['Q_Score']);
     MissionData1.add(doc.data()['Q_Target']);
   }
  }
```

But when I try to display a value inside the List in a Text widget like this:

```
Text(MissionData1 == null ?  "Loading..." : MissionData1[1],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                          color: const Color(0xFF3A404C),
                                          fontSize: 14.0.sp),),
```

He tells me there are no values ​​in the list : **RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1**

This is the Firestore Collection :

[image: Firestore Collection]

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the snapshot from `MissionRetriever1()` so `var snap` is basically equal to nothing.

Do it like this:

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot> MissionRetriever1() async{
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("quest")
        .doc("1")
        .get();
    }
```

```
Future<void> getMission1() async{
   DocumentSnapshot snap = await widget.mservice.MissionRetriever1();
   Map<String,dynamic> data = snap.data();
   MissionData1.add(data['Q_Category']);
   MissionData1.add(data['Q_Name']);
   MissionData1.add(data['Q_Description']);
   MissionData1.add(data['Q_Score']);
   MissionData1.add(data['Q_Target']);
   }
  }
```

Comment: It return this error The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot'.  Try importing the library that defines 'docs', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'.

Comment: Yes my bad, it’s a single document so you don’t need to loop through it. .docs is used for CollectionReference. I updated the answer

Comment: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Comment: Where do you get this error. Based on the screen shot of your database, the code has to work. The error might be from some other part of the code

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> MissionRetriever1() async{
QuerySnapshot querySn = await await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("quest")
    .get();
return querySn;}
```

Then querySn.docs will return a list of DocumentSnapshot. Plus your list may be [] instead of null and you try to get the first element, where there isn't one

Comment: Nope because A value of type 'DocumentSnapshot' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'QuerySnapshot'.